# Euclid' Elements Proposition VII

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I am unsure whether the last line of my proof would be consider sufficient evidence. I'll put the whole thing down for background, but feel free to scroll to the end to see the argument I am unsure about.

Show that if (a,c) = 1 = (b,c) then (ab,c) = 1.

If  ab and c are not relative primes then (ab,c) = e, where e is some integer. Since, e|c then e and a cannot have any common factors because then a and c would not be relative primes. So (a,e) = 1. Symmetric argument for (b,e) = 1. Since e is a factor of ab and e|ab then there is some integer f such that ef = ab. 
Therefore, f = ab/c however c is relative prime with both a and b and this cannot divide either without a remainder. This violates the condition that e and f are integer factors of ab and c.

It's that last paragraph where I am not sure if I am being clear enough with argument. Thanks to all in advance.